# Find out what old package versions are available in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, xgboost

I just upgraded XGBoost to its latest version (0.6). This is giving me all sort of problems with sparse matrices and would like to revert to the old version (0.4).

When I issue the following Ananconda says it can't find the package.

```
conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost=0.40
```

Is there a way from terminal to see what old versions of a package are available so that I can the choose one to use with the `conda install` command?

Answer (score 1):

The command is [`conda search`](https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-search.html). You can also add channels to the search with the `-c` flag. This command only searches channels that you specify or channels configured in your configuration file.

Another option, if you prefer a GUI or an option that searches all available channels, is to use the https://anaconda.org website.